# Center div with unknown height above the viewport's height

Tags: html, css

I'm sure that this question has been answered before but I just can't find an answer, I have a page with one main div where all the content is housed in it. I have centered it using this:

```
.center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[image: On desktop]

Which works fine when the div's height isnt larger then that of the viewport, but when it is it moves half of the content of screen. This can be easly demonstrated on mobile (see picture)

[image]

I would solve this by only applying transform on desktop but then if if the div's height where to increase the problem would reoccur. Or using some JavaScript I could check if the div's height is below that of the view port and then transform but I would prefer to keep it CSS only. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox + margin tricks:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec mi maximus, pretium nunc eget, congue nulla. Nam ornare ornare nisl accumsan suscipit. Quisque blandit tortor ac placerat lobortis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
  montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut varius a neque a venenatis. Morbi non justo dapibus, bibendum nunc vel, tempus nulla. Nam ornare, sem nec volutpat tincidunt, arcu arcu facilisis nisi, ut lobortis metus ante quis orci. In velit velit, pellentesque
  nec suscipit non, euismod nec metus. Cras pulvinar eu nisl at convallis. Nam vehicula interdum dui, sit amet vestibulum sapien consectetur id. Morbi non velit eros. Fusce ac pretium massa. Nam sit amet nibh ac magna bibendum porta. In maximus tempus
  nulla. Sed a massa ligula. Vestibulum viverra odio quis ex consequat semper. Vestibulum ex lectus, pellentesque sed quam eget, porta volutpat magna. Praesent pulvinar auctor ante, eget dictum tortor egestas non. Donec maximus sem eu nisl commodo, quis
  varius lectus suscipit. In vestibulum est diam, id ornare lacus fermentum a. Fusce dictum ligula eros, non pellentesque lorem pulvinar consectetur. Nunc sapien metus, feugiat ac sagittis sed, euismod sed purus. Curabitur quis iaculis lacus, dapibus
  ultrices leo. Curabitur ac lacinia purus. Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar erat non viverra. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In venenatis porttitor erat non eleifend. In eget auctor nulla.
  Aenean ultricies dapibus nisi eget venenatis.
</div>
```

Comment: When using this code (https://jsfiddle.net/yqjzLbo6/8/) It does indeed not move the content above the viewport, but It doesn't center it either, which is what I want.

Comment: Because there is a wrapper div in your example, updated - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJOBNx

Comment: ahaha the answer makes a lot more sense here, and it works! :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to add a `margin-top` and a `margin-bottom` to your div : on desktop, t will change nothing, but on a mobile device, your div's height will be shorter.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, I still want the div to be centered so how would I go about that? Could you maybe provide some CSS